# Node JS, how to extract X.509 Certificate from P12 file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, encryption, x509

I have `p12` file, where I should get X.509 Certificate. In order to work with this file I use `forge` library:

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
var fs = require('fs');

var keyFile = fs.readFileSync("/path/to/p12/file.p12", 'binary');
var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(keyFile);

var p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, 'password');

var bags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag});

var cert = bags[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];

console.log(cert);
```

Console outputs to me this kind of information:

```
{ type: '1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.3',
  attributes:
  { localKeyId: [ 'aoa ??xx\u0015-?]%m§ §\f,\u0013' ],
    friendlyName: [ 'e56fe5a0899f787815adaf5d256da7a0a70c2c13' ] },
    cert: null,
    asn1:
    { tagClass: 0,
      type: 16,
      constructed: true,
      composed: true,
      value: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

This result means that I have an alias with name `e56fe5a0899f787815adaf5d256da7a0a70c2c13`, but why `cert` is `null`?

There is Java's security api's, which is able to extract X.509 certificate from this p12 file by it's alias.

```
X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
```

How it is possible to extract X.509 certificate from `p12` file by using `forge`?

Node version `5.4.1`

Forge Version `0.6.45`

There you can download my testing p12 file: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Xi-qhe93I8QjYzcndoTmhFazQ)

password is `123456`

Comment: Can you show the test certificate with such behavior? Which version of the `node.js` and `forge` library?

Comment: @stdob-- I have updated my answer. As for showing certificate, you mean upload `p12` file?

Comment: Yes if it is possible. In my environment (node 5.4.1 & forge 0.6.45), your code on my certificate gives the correct result.

Comment: @stdob-- I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/237#issuecomment-93555599]:

> If forge doesn't recognize the key format, it will return null for the
>   key property in the key bag, and set an asn1 property with the raw
>   ASN.1 representation of the key.

So, you need [`convert to ASN.1, then DER, then PEM-encode`](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/237#issuecomment-93757363):

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
var fs = require('fs');

var keyFile = fs.readFileSync("./gost.p12", 'binary');
var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(keyFile);

var p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, '123456');

var bags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag});

var bag = bags[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];

// convert to ASN.1, then DER, then PEM-encode
var msg = {
  type: 'CERTIFICATE',
  body: forge.asn1.toDer(bag.asn1).getBytes()
};
var pem = forge.pem.encode(msg);

console.log(pem);
```