# Get cert body and private key from p12 node-forge

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get the certificate body and key (PEM format) from a p12 instance from node-forge.

[I saw this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864348/node-js-how-to-extract-x-509-certificate-from-p12-file#answer-40885190) to a similar question but from some reason it doesn't work for me.

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
var fs = require('fs');

var keyFile = fs.readFileSync("./gost.p12", 'binary');
var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(keyFile);

var p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, '123456');

var bags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag});

var bag = bags[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];

// convert to ASN.1, then DER, then PEM-encode
var msg = {
  type: 'CERTIFICATE',
  body: forge.asn1.toDer(bag.asn1).getBytes()
};
var pem = forge.pem.encode(msg);

console.log(pem);
```

`bag.asn1` isn't something that exists on the bag instance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It would be much simpler task if you know what kind of private key used in your .p12 file:

1) In case of RSA key you can get private key from "p12" object by [example](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#pkcs12) from official repository of "node-forge":

```
// get key bags
var bags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.keyBag});
// get key
var bag = bags[forge.pki.oids.keyBag][0];
var key = bag.key;
```

2) In my case it was PKCS8 key. To get it you can use [example](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/292#issuecomment-137457845) from "node-forge" issues:

```
var keyBags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag});
var bag = keyBags[forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag][0];
var privateKey = bag.key;
```

3) In case of ECC key "node-forge" is not an option according to following open issue: ["PKCS12 to PEM"](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/576)

> Unfortunately, we haven't yet implemented ASN.1 parsing for ECC keys, only RSA keys. Forge has an implementation for ed25519 but using only the raw (much simpler) format. PRs are welcome!

Comment: 1) does not work for me. bag is undefined. Though i previously created the certificate with node-forge using pki.rsa.generateKeyPair(...)

Comment: update: 2) seems to work. at least it is not empty. strange.